# List out keys of an Object depending on the frequency of a value in that object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have an Object

```
const usersList = {
user2: 6
user7: 3
user2627: 0
user7327: 0
user10780: 8
user13116: 0
user14842: 2
user17172: 1
user20566: 2
user21632: 0
user27366: 2
user29127: 0
user30024: 0
user30332: 6
user31870: 6
user33550: 8
user34407: 5
user34429: 4
user36495: 0
user38639: 2
};
```

I want to list out the keys which has values more than 5. can I do it using filter the value more than 5 or any other way which will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a `filter()` on `Object.keys()`

```js
const usersList={user2:6,user7:3,user2627:0,user7327:0,user10780:8,user13116:0,user14842:2,user17172:1,user20566:2,user21632:0,user27366:2,user29127:0,user30024:0,user30332:6,user31870:6,user33550:8,user34407:5,user34429:4,user36495:0,user38639:2};

const res = Object.keys(usersList).filter(k => usersList[k] > 5)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: how can I show the values of res in a `ul li` element by iterating over them?

Comment: Same way you would with any other array. Please update question to show sample of expected results as per [mcve]

Comment: by mapping? or by using toString()? could you please provide a code block of what you are suggesting?

Comment: Well if you want a new <li> for each would need to loop over array and create and insert each one

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
Object.keys(usersList).filter(key => usersList[key] > 5)
```